# ChartJS make the data value on chart more bigger and bold

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I'm struggling a bit with trying to show the data value on top of the bar charts more bigger and bolder. At the moment it's coming out so small that hardly anyone can see.
This is the code i'm using:

```
onComplete: function () {
  var chartInstance = this.chart;
      // ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
      // ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      // ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
      // ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

      this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
              var data = dataset.data[index];
              ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 10);

          });
      });
  }
```

This is how the data looks at the moment:

[image]

As you can see it's very tiny the numbers on top of the bar. What can i change to make it bigger and bold. Tried searching the net but o no avail.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears as if you are drawing/writing to the canvas' context directly, one approach would be to use the respective `.font` property of the context.

> I assume that - since `ctx` is commented out in your example - you are requesting the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` somewhere in your code via `.getContext('2d')` and store it in a variable `ctx` that you use later inside the `onComplete` callback.

You can find examples about the usage of the `.font` property on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font), however it should/could look like:

```
ctx.font = 'bold 20px sans-serif';
```

where `20px` defines the font size.